# Change text on button in datalist not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code and it works to change the URL, but it does not change the text on the button.  What am I missing? The button is in a datalist and I want to change the Text on the button when pressed.  What is supposed to happen is the user hits the Quiz button and the URL should change to the quizURL(this works).  At the same time the text on the button should change to say Video(this doesn't work).  Then when the user hits the same button it will toggle back to the quiz.  I'm trying to have one button act as a toggle to show the quiz or the video.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnQuizVid" runat="server" Text="Quiz" CommandName="quiz" CssClass="buttonStyleGrey" />


protected void trainingDataList_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    List<Material> dataset = null;
    string btnText = ((Button)(trainingDataList.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("btnQuizVid"))).Text;

    if (e.CommandName == "quiz")
    {
        dataset = BasicCRUDtoolkit.GetMaterialByProfFocus(hdnTypeSelect.Value);
        Button tmpBtn = e.Item.FindControl("btnQuizVid") as Button;

        if (btnText == "Quiz")
        {
            tmpBtn.Text = "Video";
            tmpBtn.DataBind();
            dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].videoURL = dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].quizURL;

        }
        else
        {
            tmpBtn.Text = "Quiz";
            dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].videoURL = dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].videoURL;

        }

        trainingDataList.DataSource = dataset;
        trainingDataList.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `OnCommand` value in your button markup, thus the `CommandName` value you are setting in the markup does not know what to call when fired. Add the `OnCommand` value to your button markup, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnQuizVid" runat="server" Text="Quiz" CommandName="quiz" 
            CssClass="buttonStyleGrey" 
            OnCommand="trainingDataList_ItemCommand" />
```

Get the button control once and do not call `.DataBind()` on the button as the change will be reflected just by changing the `Text` property, because the code is executing before the HTML is sent to the browser. Change your code to this:

```
protected void trainingDataList_ItemCommand(object source, 
                                            DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    List<Material> dataset = null;
    var theButton = trainingDataList.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex]
                                    .FindControl("btnQuizVid") as Button;

    if (e.CommandName == "quiz")
    {
        dataset = BasicCRUDtoolkit.GetMaterialByProfFocus(hdnTypeSelect.Value);

        if (theButton.Text == "Quiz")
        {
            theButton.Text = "Video";
            dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].videoURL = dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].quizURL;
        }
        else
        {
            theButton.Text = "Quiz";
            dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].videoURL = dataset[e.Item.ItemIndex].videoURL;
        }

        trainingDataList.DataSource = dataset;
        trainingDataList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this prior to posting, and again after your suggestion.  No luck.  With our without databinding the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do `Button tmpBtn = e.Item.FindControl("btnQuizVid") as Button;` and `theButton.Text = "Video";` after `DataBind()`;

Comment: I tried your suggestion and did all of the button handling after the trainingDataList.DataBind() call.  This did not work.  Any suggestions?